# Which errors should I handle? Which ones are "fatal"?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, error-handling, error-code

Some Windows functions such as `CreateFile` could return a *huge* variety of error codes when `GetLastError` is called, and it's impractical to check for every possible error code -- there is often not enough documentation, and new error codes are added frequently.

Some of them (such as access violations or invalid parameters) are due to programmer error and should not allow continuation of program execution. However, others are due to other factors, such as bad file permissions, sharing violations, bad file names, etc., which the developer has little or no control over.

I would like to handle all "non-critical" errors (such as bad file names), while allowing "critical errors" (such as access violations) to crash my program.

Ideally, I would be saying:

```
// ... an error occurred. Is it a programmer error?

if (IsErrorCritical(GetLastError()))
{
    // Yes; raise an exception, crashing the program.
    RaiseException(GetLastError(), 0, 0, NULL);
}
```

How do I decide which error codes are safe to suppress (for example, when enumerating files on a disk), when I cannot possibly predict each and every outcome?

Comment: I would argue that a program should never crash except in truly exceptional circumstances (access violation, etc).  Failing to create a file should be an expected failure and handled in a graceful manner.  Besides, as soon as some new error code is added your IsErrorCritical() function would become outdated.

Comment: Right, but how do I know if something is "truly exceptional"? That's the question..

Comment: When I say exceptional I mean exactly that.  Access violations and running out of memory are the two big ones; there may be others, but you get the idea.  If CreateFile() failing causes your program to crash then you're doing it wrong IMHO.

Comment: @Luke: Are you suggesting that I should whitelist error codes, or blacklist them?

Comment: I would only ever crash on *exceptions* (e.g. Windows structured exceptions such as access violation, stack overflow, etc), maybe out of memory conditions, things of that nature.  I would not try to generalize this around specific GetLastError() codes.

Comment: @Luke: What about errors like `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`, `ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES`, etc.? Shouldn't they be treated the same way as out-of-memory conditions?

Comment: INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER is typically an indication that you didn't pass a large enough buffer to some function.  NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES might be a good candidate, but it is still highly dependent on what function you are calling.  It may be fatal in one scenario and recoverable in another.  If you try to use a one size fits all approach then sooner or later you are going to get burned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it really depends on the context, it is impossible to generally decide this instead it needs to be decided on a case by case basis.

The reason I say this is that sometimes the same error code comes in different contexts so its not the error code itself that can be used to determine if it is critical but the context itself.

Answer (score 4):

"Critical" depends on what you're doing with the file.

Any error code could be because of either programmer error, or some exceptional thing on the running machine; I don't think that is an important distinction in error handling.

For the errors you don't handle specifically (the "unknown" ones), just assume the file was not created, and handle that case. It doesn't matter WHY it wasn't created, just assume it wasn't and account for that scenario. Depending on what your code is doing and how much effort you want to put into this scenario, it may be fatal or not.

Note that access violations are not something that `GetLastError()` knows about, so I don't understand its relevance to your question.

Comment: Actually, I *have* gotten access violations back from `GetLastError`. Not with `CreateFile` of course, but from other functions (I don't remember which ones, unfortunately). But good point anyway, +1.

Comment: What does it mean to "get an access violation back from getlasterror"?

Comment: It means I've received `ERROR_NOACCESS` returned from GetLastError, but I don't remember what function I got it for.